# How do I query to pull all data in row based MIN and MAX service date?

Tags: oracle, query

I'm very new to Oracle SQL especially in the Pentaho report builder.  It lets you do some things and block others.  PL/SQL is not available so I must do this in a query.

I need to be able to pull all the data in each row for a client for their `MIN(service_date)` and their `MAX(service_date)`.  Below are the table data and the result I'd like to get.

**Table Data**

```
client_id | service_date  | other_stuff 
--------------------------------------- 
        1 | 2/24/2010     | Bob
        1 | 3/23/2010     | Jane
        1 | 4/23/2010     | Sam
        2 | 1/1/2000      | Julie
        2 | 2/2/2000      | Tina
        3 | 3/28/2005     | D'Shaun
        3 | 4/27/2005     | Leisha
        3 | 5/29/2005     | Tonay
```

**Result data**

```
client_id | service_date | other_stuff
--------------------------------------
        1 | 2/24/2010     | Bob
        1 | 4/23/2010     | Sam
        2 | 1/1/2000      | Julie
        2 | 2/2/2000      | Tina
        3 | 3/28/2005     | D'Shaun
        3 | 5/29/2005     | Tonay
```

Answer (score 9):

There might be other better ways but does following work for you?

```
select client_id
      ,service_date
      ,other_stuff
  from (
        select client_id
              ,service_date
              ,other_stuff
              ,row_number() over (partition by client_id order by service_date) rn_min
              ,row_number() over (partition by client_id order by service_date desc) rn_max
          from tbl
       )
 where (rn_min = 1 OR rn_max = 1) ;
```

Comment: There are variations on this method, but this version is probably the simplest. Analytic/window functions are definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work. You can check it at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/485d5/1/0). The primary guarantees that there will be returned only one row per `client_id` and `service_date`. SQL Fiddle shows that the plan differs to that of the answer of [@Narendra](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/485d5/2/0). The latter shows a full table scan. But he size of the test data set is very small.

```
create table client_usage(
  client_id number,
  service_date date,
  other_stuff varchar2(30) not null,
  constraint pk_client_usage 
    primary key(client_id,service_date)
);

insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff) 
  values(1,to_date('2/24/2010','mm/dd/yyyy'),' Bob ');
insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff) 
  values(1,to_date('3/23/2010','mm/dd/yyyy'),' Jane ');
insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff) 
  values(1,to_date('4/23/2010','mm/dd/yyyy'),' Sam ');
insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff) 
  values(2,to_date('1/1/2000','mm/dd/yyyy'),' Julie ');
insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff)       
  values(2,to_date('2/2/2000','mm/dd/yyyy'),' Tina ');
insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff) 
  values(3,to_date('3/28/2005','mm/dd/yyyy'),' D''Shaun ');
insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff) 
  values(3,to_date('4/27/2005','mm/dd/yyyy'),' Leisha ');
insert into client_usage(client_id,service_date,other_stuff) 
  values(3,to_date('5/29/2005','mm/dd/yyyy'),' Tonay ');


select client_id,service_date,other_stuff
  from client_usage
  where (client_id,service_date) in(
    select client_id,min(service_date)
       from client_usage
       group by client_id
     union all select client_id,max(service_date)
       from client_usage
       group by client_id
  );
```

I tried both queries on different datasets with 1 000 000 rows: `max_i` is the number of different `clients_ids`, `max_j` is the number of entries (`service_dates`) per client. `random` means that the `service_dates` where inserted at random into the table, `increasing` or `decreasing` means that they were inserted in inreasing or decreasing order. The first method is my method, the second one is that of @Narendra.

```
random, max_i=10, max_j=100000
00:00:01.32 00:00:08.00
random, max_i=1000, max_j=1000
00:00:01.83 00:00:08.35
random, max_i=100000, max_j=10
00:00:05.80 00:00:10.45
inceasing, max_i=10, max_j=100000
00:00:01.45 00:00:08.80
inceasing, max_i=1000, max_j=1000
00:00:01.99 00:00:08.84
inceasing, max_i=100000, max_j=10
00:00:05.49 00:00:10.97
decreasing, max_i=10, max_j=100000
00:00:01.48 00:00:08.54
decreasing, max_i=1000, max_j=1000
00:00:01.98 00:00:08.59
decreasing, max_i=100000, max_j=10
00:00:05.58 00:00:11.04
```

[Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1822122724803) mentions that sorting in both directions brings additional performance degradiation.

Comment: I reviewd the oracle plan and saw that my query also contains a full table scan. I will investigate the performance further.

Comment: perhaps a better plan: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc0ee/1

Comment: @LeighRiffel: as far as I can see both queries are semantically equivalent so a perfect optimizer should create the same plan for them. currently I am not sure which one would perform better on a larger dataset if the optimizer is not so perfect.

Comment: @LeighRiffel: sorting the windows is costly. In the following there is only one client id with about 788K different service_dates : http://pastebin.com/PdQ85iM9

Comment: @LeighRiffel: both statements query the same table with the same (primary key) index created with the create statement of my post. but the second query does not use it. the table contains 788K rows with client_id=1 , other_stuff='dummy stuff' and different service_dates (so  the first client_usage was some thousand years b.c.)

Comment: Despite my initial misgivings it appears that miracle173's solution does indeed perform faster for various data-sets I have tried. The reduced disk access for an answer like Narendra's does not seem to make up for the massive sorting that must be done.  Your mileage may vary depending on disk and CPU speeds. +1

Comment: @LeighRiffel: Added my testscript (run.sql), auxiliary scripts and results (measure.lst) if you are interested in http://pastebin.com/CicYB2C8